# How to pass json encoded php array to google maps latlng to redraw polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been working on redrawing polygons onto a google map but am stuck now.

I have a php array gathering latitude and longitude info from a mysql database.
which is then json encoded to be used in javascript.
The json gives me what i need, but my question is how do i process the json further
to be used in the new google.maps.LatLng(); constructor when it needs 2 parameters??

Here is what have so far.
The json looks like this printed out:

["-29.446736427714118\r\n-28.562776229541612\r\n151.33620268749996\r\n150.85280424999996\r\n"]

It gives me my numbers in an array as i need it but how do i pass it as 2 parameters
into the following code??

Thanks to anyone in advanced!!

```
var coords = [  

var polygons = [];


    var pol = new google.maps.LatLng(Latit,Longit);

];
```

//Construct the polygon
  polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
   path: coords

}));
  polygons[polygons.length-1].setMap(map); //Your map ob